# Create UIView programmatically without Interface Builder

Tags: objective-c, ios

I try to create a view without IB and make it separated with its controller. The view is MediaPlayerView contains two buttons and the controller is MediaPlayerViewController. I called the view in controller and adding a Movie Player view in it. The buttons is showing but the movie view just dark screen. What's wrong with my code?

Here is my code:

MediaPlayerView.m

```
-(id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
        UIButton *audioFileButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
        UIButton *shortSoundButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];

        [audioFileButton setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 40, 150, 40)];
        [shortSoundButton setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 100, 200, 40)];

        [audioFileButton setTitle:@"Play Audio File" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [shortSoundButton setTitle:@"Play Short Sound" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        _viewController = [[MediaPlayerViewController alloc] init];
        [audioFileButton addTarget:[self viewController]
                            action:@selector(playAudioFile:)
                  forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [shortSoundButton addTarget:[self viewController]
                             action:@selector(playShortSound:)
                   forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

        [self addSubview:audioFileButton];
        [self addSubview:shortSoundButton];
    }
    return self;
}
```

In MediaPlayerViewController.m, here is my loadView and viewDidLoad:

loadView:

```
MediaPlayerView *mPlayer = [[MediaPlayerView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
[mPlayer setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[self setView:mPlayer];
[mPlayer release];
```

viewDidLoad:

```
[super viewDidLoad];
float halfHeight = [[self view] bounds].size.height / 2.0;
float width = [[self view] bounds].size.width;

[[[self moviePlayer] view] setFrame:CGRectMake(0, halfHeight, width, halfHeight)];
[[self view] addSubview:[[self moviePlayer] view]];
```

Forgive for my bad writing, cause I am a newbie either in here, Objective-C or english.